# Apple App Site Association File Download Error

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

We are trying to add universal link functionality to our app and currently trying to test this in one of our test environments.

We are currently seeing issues with the download of the file to the device but the console log entry doesn't give us much to go on:

```
### Download URL 'https://our.test.domain.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association' failed: -6756/0xFFFFE59C kTypeErr
```

Can anyone help with understanding what is going wrong with the download?

We're aware that Apple have an on-line tool for validating the structure of this file but because our test environment is behind a firewall then the tool can't get to the file, this leads to two additional questions:

Does anyone know the IP range we would have to allow through for this tool to work?

Is anyone aware of a tool that will validate the structure of the file by uploading the file contents rather than pointing it at the URL of the file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns the I did need to follow the format outlined here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

```
{
   "applinks": {
   "apps": [],
   "details": [{
     "appID": "12345NGB.co.uk.my.app",
     "paths": ["/universallink/*"]
   }]
 }
}
```

The Apple documentation is very misleading because it suggests that's an old format for supporting iOS 12 and earlier.